# Delete files from Windows 2008 file explorer using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to delete log files using a task scheduler from a 2008 Windows server that'll be run using a task scheduler. I've created my own and used online scripts but nothing has worked. After running the the script manually on the server a prompt appears that halts this process (which seems to be the issue). Below is a script that I've run on my pc that worked and the OS is Windows 1903 and it worked. The only discrepancy that I could this of is that the PowerShell versions are different. Could someone provide advice as to why is doesn't delete files on a Windows 2008 OS?

Skeleton Script:

Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\path\to\folder" -Recurse | 
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt 
(Get-Date).AddDays(-60))} | Remove-Item

Comment: [1] what is the FULL text of the error message? i suspect it has to do with your `Remove-Item` line. if you don't have the error msg, try adding `Start-Transcript` to the top of the script & have it write to a place that the account has access to. [2] what are the PS versions involved?

Comment: What is the prompt that appears? And you're not deleting from the *file explorer*. You're deleting from the file system. Explorer has absolutely nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: Change remove-item to remove-item -Confirm:$false -force  It will stop asking you to confirm the deleting of files.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron,

Change remove-item to remove-item -Confirm:$false -force It will stop asking you to confirm the deleting of files. – Aaron

**This solved the issue.**